# Trigonometric Identity $\arcsin(\alpha+\beta)=\arcsin(\alpha|\sec(\beta)|)+\arcsin(\beta|\sec(\alpha)|)$

Tags: trigonometry

Is this trigonometric identity is true?
$$\arcsin(\alpha+\beta)=\arcsin(\alpha|\sec(\beta)|)+\arcsin(\beta|\sec(\alpha)|).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Try $\alpha = \beta =\frac12$.